# Wi-fi does not work on a RedmiBook 16 laptop

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, drivers

I bought a RedmiBook 16 laptop. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it, Wi-fi does not work on it. It's not even in the settings.
[image]

Wi-fi can be found by searching. But you can't turn it on. There's not even a slider for it.
[image]

At the same time, when connected via a wire, the Internet works.
Below are the conclusions of the commands.

**sudo rfkill list all**

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
```

**lspci | grep Network**

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
```

**dmesg | grep ath10k**

```
[    2.436543] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.438420] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    2.709192] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 11ad:0847
[    2.709194] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    2.709724] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00140-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,mfp crc32 29eb8ca1
[    2.776665] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to fetch board data for bus=pci,vendor=168c,device=003e,subsystem-vendor=11ad,subsystem-device=0847 from ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
[    2.776887] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: board_file api 1 bmi_id N/A crc32 ed5f849a
[    3.591641] Modules linked in: nls_iso8859_1 snd_acp3x_rn snd_soc_dmic snd_acp3x_pdm_dma snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep ath10k_pci edac_mce_amd ath10k_core kvm_amd snd_pcm ath snd_seq_midi kvm amdgpu snd_seq_midi_event crct10dif_pclmul mac80211 joydev snd_rawmidi ghash_clmulni_intel cfg80211 aesni_intel crypto_simd btusb efi_pstore btrtl cryptd glue_helper btbcm snd_seq iommu_v2 btintel gpu_sched input_leds rapl bluetooth snd_seq_device ttm snd_timer drm_kms_helper cec cdc_ether usbnet rc_core r8152 i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops syscopyarea mii ecdh_generic sysfillrect ecc sysimgblt snd hid_multitouch ucsi_acpi serio_raw snd_rn_pci_acp3x typec_ucsi k10temp libarc4 ccp snd_pci_acp3x typec mac_hid wmi_bmof soundcore sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic crc32_pclmul i2c_piix4 ahci
[    6.039155] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to ping firmware: -110
[    6.039162] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to reset rx filter: -110
[    6.119275] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not init core (-110)
[    6.119299] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not probe fw (-110)
```

Please tell me what I need to do to fix the problem. At the moment, I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with proprietary driver:

1. sudo wget http://www.killernetworking.com/support/K1535_Debian/board.bin -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
2. sudo wget https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/raw/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/4.4.1/firmware-6.bin_WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00132-QCARMSWP-1 -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-6.bin
3. sudo rm /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin